# Making waterfall chart using PowerPoint chart in VSTO

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I am making a
**Waterfall chart** in a **PowerPoint** add-in using **VSTO**.

```
PowerPoint.Slide slide = null;
PowerPoint.Shape shape = null;
PowerPoint.Chart chart = null;
```

This lines tells what kind of chart to make.

```
shape = slide.Shapes.AddChart(Office.XlChartType.xlColumnStacked, 200, 200, 300, 200);
```

This line here opens an Excel workbook which makes the chart when data is added into it.

```
chart = shape.Chart;
```

Here is an image of the chart that I create.[image: My Waterfall chart]

Now the problem is, I want the 2nd bar to be plotted form the end of the 1st bar i.e from 4 instead of 0 on the x-axis.

Like this.

[image: The Real Waterfall Chart]

Can someone tell me is there any way I can draw my series from the value of the previous series instead of 0 value of x-axis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think Excel or PowerPoint charts supports waterfalls out of the box. However, you can do this by keeping the chart type as **stacked** and adding a separate *helper chart series* that is invisible and pushes the other series up. Then it is all about calculating the different values for this *helper chart series* based on the previous values of the actual chart series.

By invisible, I imply making both the line and the fill **none**. The chart series will still be there, but you just won't see it unless you start editing the chart.

Answer (score 0):

I created waterfall chart from Stacked column chart and used the Workbook object from the Chartdata of the Selected shape.
You can follow this [link](http://www.indezine.com/articles/waterfall-chart-in-powerpoint-part-1.html) to check how to create waterfall chart manually..and then manipulate the Worksheet/datasheet of the chart through code to create Waterfall chart.
Here is a snippet of my code..

```
 private void calculationAndFormatting(bool excelEvent,Excel.Worksheet Sheet)
    {
        //unregister from Excel Change Event

        Sheet.Application.EnableEvents = false;

                int lRow = 1;
                lRow = iRowCount;

                Sheet.Range["A1", "A" + lRow].Copy(Type.Missing);
                Sheet.Range["B" + (lRow + 5)].PasteSpecial(Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteAll, Excel.XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, false, false);
                Sheet.Range["B1", "B" + lRow].Copy(Type.Missing);
                Sheet.Range["A" + (lRow + 5)].PasteSpecial(Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteAll, Excel.XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, false, false);
                Sheet.Range["B1", "D1"].Copy(Type.Missing);
                Sheet.Range["C" + (lRow + 5)].PasteSpecial(Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteAll, Excel.XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, false, false);
                int ulRow = Sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
                int k=ulRow;
                if (!excelEvent)
                {
                    Sheet.Range["C" + (lRow + 6)].Value = "0";
                    Sheet.Range["C" + (ulRow + 1)].Value = "0";

                    Sheet.Range["A" + (ulRow + 1)].Value = "=SUM(A" + (lRow + 5) + ":" + "A" + ulRow + ")";
                    Sheet.Range["B" + (ulRow + 1)].Value = "Total Value";
                    k = ulRow + 1;
                }              
                for (int i = lRow + 6; i <= k; i++)
                {
                    if (Sheet.Range["A" + i].Value < 0)
                    {
                        if (i <= k-1 && i != lRow + 6)
                        {
                            Sheet.Range["C" + i].Formula = "=E" + (i - 1) + "+" + "A" + i;
                        }
                        Sheet.Range["D" + i].Formula = "=-A" + i;
                        Sheet.Range["E" + i].Formula = "=C" + i;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (i <= k-1 && i != lRow + 6)
                        {
                            Sheet.Range["C" + i].Formula = "=E" + (i - 1);
                        }
                        Sheet.Range["D" + i].Formula = "=A" + i;
                        Sheet.Range["E" + i].Formula = "=C" + i + "+" + "D" + i;
                    }

            }
                string sourceCol = "='" + Sheet.Name + "'!$C$" + (lRow + 5) + ":$E$" + (k);
                pChart.SetSourceData(sourceCol, PowerPoint.XlRowCol.xlColumns);


                PowerPoint.Axis axis = pChart.Axes(PowerPoint.XlAxisType.xlValue);
                axis.MaximumScale = 1.25 * (System.Double)Sheet.Range["D" + (k)].Value;
                axis.MinimumScale = 0.0;
                PowerPoint.Axis catAxis = pChart.Axes(PowerPoint.XlAxisType.xlCategory);

                catAxis.CategoryNames = Sheet.Range["B" + (lRow + 6), "B" + (k)].Value;
                                applyFormatting();
                drawLeaderLines(Sheet);
            Sheet.Application.EnableEvents = true;
            Sheet = null;

    }
```

Comment: My bad..I have the c# version too..Tag totally skipped from my mind.